# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not work in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET project and I need to decode escaped emoji symbols. I use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode for it, but it doesn't work.

```
var s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#128512;");
output: s => &#128512;
```

But if I create new console application and write

```
var s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#128512;");
```

then s = 😀

Why in the first case it doesn't work, but works in the second?

Comment: You say you use 'HttpUtility.HtmlDecode' then demo 'WebUtility.HtmlDecode' is this on purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I used HttpUtility and WebUtility. In my case their behavior identical

Comment: I just verified. It;s perfectly working with  ASP.NET as well. 
are you missing any details.?